# How could we display all informations present in the specific row using python

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

[I'm new to SQLite so please don't be rude on me]

I have created a database with a table

```
 CREATE TABLE `Pensioners` (
    `AccountNo` INTEGER,
    `Name`  TEXT,
    `Initial`   TEXT,
    `Retired`   BLOB,
    PRIMARY KEY(AccountNo)
)
```

and I have coded a program to insert values into the database

```
 var = '''INSERT INTO Pensioners(AccountNo,Name,Initial,Retired)VALUES(?,?,?,?)'''
                cur.execute(var,(acc.get(),nam.get(),init.get(),rd.get()))
                messagebox.showinfo("Success", "Details Added!")
```

here acc, nam, etc., are variables from the entry widget. The details have been added successfully.

What I am expecting my program to do is:

If I type the account the program should display the name of the persion and his/her other details.

What I have tried is:

```
for accno in search.get(),:
           cur.execute('SELECT count(*) FROM Pensioners WHERE AccountNo = ?',(accno,))
           base = cur.fetchone()[0]
           if base>0:
              dis = Label(text=base,fg='black').place(x=10,y=480)
           else:
               messagebox.showinfo("Error", "No results found")
```

Example of my expectation:
account no: 123456789
output:
John
P
31/01/2016 [These are the values added to the database for the specific account no]

but I get weird values like 1 etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I have figured out finally I must have dig the book more

```
var2 = str(search.get())
   variable = '''SELECT * FROM Pensioners WHERE AccountNo ='''+var2
   cur.execute(variable)
   for row in cur.fetchall():
           dis = Label(text=row,fg='black').place(x=10,y=480)
```